# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1):

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to use Sqlite in android studio, and I want to use the following code to search "Destination" object using id number.

```
private final static  String DATABASE_NAME = "Destination.db";

private final static  int  DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

//table name
private final static  String TABLE_NAME = "Destination";

public final static  String DESTINATION_ID = "destination_id";

public final static  String DESTINATION_NAME = "destination_name";

public final static  String DESTINATION_PRIORITY = "destination_priority";

public final static  String DESTINATION_LONGITUDE = "destination_longitude";

public final static  String DESTINATION_LATITUDE = "destination_latitude";
```

the names are above, and here is my code:

```
 public Destination getDestination(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery="SELECT "+
            DESTINATION_ID + "," +
            DESTINATION_NAME + "," +
            DESTINATION_PRIORITY + "," +
            DESTINATION_LONGITUDE + "," +
            DESTINATION_LATITUDE + "," +
            " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " +
            DESTINATION_ID + "=?";

    Destination destination = new Destination();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            destination.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESTINATION_ID)));
            destination.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESTINATION_NAME)));
            destination.setPriority(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESTINATION_PRIORITY)));
            destination.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESTINATION_LONGITUDE)));
            destination.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DESTINATION_LATITUDE)));
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return destination;

}
```

the information in logCAT is:
 [image: see picture here]

It seems that something is wrong with the select query:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

why is it ?? I am a beginner in sqlite, and please help me!! thank you!

Comment: You have an extra comma after `DESTINATION_LATITUDE` in `selectQuery`.

Comment: Use this As Per Mike Suggestions String selectQuery="SELECT "+
            DESTINATION_ID + "," +
            DESTINATION_NAME + "," +
            DESTINATION_PRIORITY + "," +
            DESTINATION_LONGITUDE + "," +
            DESTINATION_LATITUDE +
            " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " +
            DESTINATION_ID + "=?";

Comment: thanks all for helping!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove last , from selectQuery.

```
String selectQuery="SELECT "+
        DESTINATION_ID + "," +
        DESTINATION_NAME + "," +
        DESTINATION_PRIORITY + "," +
        DESTINATION_LONGITUDE + "," +
        DESTINATION_LATITUDE  +
        " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
        + " WHERE " +
        DESTINATION_ID + "=?";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this remove ","

```
String selectQuery="SELECT "+
            DESTINATION_ID + "," +
            DESTINATION_NAME + "," +
            DESTINATION_PRIORITY + "," +
            DESTINATION_LONGITUDE + "," +
            DESTINATION_LATITUDE  +
            " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
            + " WHERE " +
            DESTINATION_ID + "=?";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a trailing comma in your list of fields.

```
String selectQuery="SELECT "+
        DESTINATION_ID + "," +
        DESTINATION_NAME + "," +
        DESTINATION_PRIORITY + "," +
        DESTINATION_LONGITUDE + "," +
        DESTINATION_LATITUDE + "," +   // This will appear as
        " FROM " + TABLE_NAME          // "destination_latitude, FROM"
        + " WHERE " +
        DESTINATION_ID + "=?";
```

Remove the comma after DESTINATION_LATITUDE and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `,` from the code and modify it

```
String selectQuery="SELECT "+
        DESTINATION_ID + "," +
        DESTINATION_NAME + "," +
        DESTINATION_PRIORITY + "," +
        DESTINATION_LONGITUDE + "," +
        DESTINATION_LATITUDE +
        " FROM " + TABLE_NAME
        + " WHERE " +
        DESTINATION_ID + "=?";
```